# How can I animate and rotation this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html code:

```
<div class="block-1"></div>
<div class="block-2"></div>
<div class="block-3"></div>
```

And I need in this algorithm:

1. For **.block-1** add class **active**
2. *Wait 500 ms.* - for **.block-2** add class **active**
3. *Wait 400 ms.* - for **.block-3** add class **active**
4. *Wait 500 ms.* - remove all classes **active** and repeat all

But there are some problems...

This is animation:

**.block-1** has styles `height: 0; transition: height .5s linear;`

.block-1.active has styles `height: 100px;`

So, block height varies from 0px to 100px for 500 ms.

I tried to add **delay**:

```
$('.block-1').addClass('active');
$('.block-2').delay(500).addClass('active');
$('.block-3').delay(900).addClass('active');
...
```

But **delay** doesn't won't correctly with **addClass**.

P.S. I need in addClass. I can't use animate, such as

```
$('.block-1').animate({height: 100px}, 500);
```

...because this is only demo code and in my real code I have not only one **height**, but a lot of other properties.

The next problem is **delay**. **Delay** is considered from the beginning, and I need write code such as:

1. First step
2. Second step - delay 500
3. Third step - delay 900
4. Forth step - delay 1200
5. ...

But I have about 40 steps and if I try to edit one of this steps I'll born a lot of problems...

P.S. Sorry for my bad English (I am form St. Petersburg).

Comment: If the height always 100 for every block? You could use `transition-delay: .500s;` in CSS if each of the block already has a style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So many of them.. Do it like... Less confusing way...

```
function doStuff()
{
          $('.block-1').addClass('active');
          setTimeout(function() {  $('.block-2').addClass('active');  }, 500);
          setTimeout(function() { $('.block-3').addClass('active'); }, 900);
          setTimeout(function() { $('.block-1, .block-2, .block-3').removeClass('active'); },1300);

}

doStuff();

setInterval(function() { doStuff();  }, 1400);
```

Comment: How to get rid of the delay in the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds wonky, but:

```
setInterval(function() {
  $('.block-1').addClass('active');
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.block-2').addClass('active');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('.block-3').addClass('active');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.block-1, .block-2, .block-3').removeClass('active');
      }, 500);
    }, 400);
  }, 500);
}, 1400);
```

Comment: Works best only first time. The second time and more **.block-1** does not have time to animate... And how to get rid of the delay in the beginning?

[link](http://jsfiddle.net/Lashchevsky/uuufhhky/)

Comment: Should probably just use animation keyframes, obviously this isn't a great task for javascript... http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/

Answer (score 0):

If I got you in a right way, you want to wait until transition on your block ends to make active another block, so you can just catch the `transitionEnd` event and then add your next class like:

```
$('#block-1').
addClass('active').
on('transitionEnd webkitTransitionEnd mozTransitionEnd 
  msTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd ', function(){
  $('#block-2').addClass('class-2').on(/*so on here*/);
  //
})
```